# Rust - how to split/ flatten an iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator

If I have a `vec<string>` I can use `filter_map` to process and eliminate entires. But is there an option opposite of `filter` ?

Essentially is there an idiomatic way to do something like this -

```rust
word_list.iter().merge_map(|s| s.split(".")).collect()
                 ^this is an imaginary method.
```

Turning an input `["a","b.c","d"]` into `["a","b","c","d"]`

Answer (score 6):

Use [`flat_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map):

```rust
word_list.iter().flat_map(|s| s.split(".")).collect()
```

Which is semantically equivalent to [`map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) then [`flatten()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten):

```rust
word_list.iter().map(|s| s.split(".")).flatten().collect()
```